# Log of SQL queries to ODBC driver?

Tags: windows-xp, sql-server, sql, odbc

I have an application on my Windows XP SP3 machine that's querying and returning data from a database through the SQL Server Native Client.

**Is there a log file being kept that would show me the SQL queries?**

Comment: What do you mean by the queries - a log of when the query ran, what data was requested, what data was brought  back? All of the above or non? :)

Comment: All of the above.

Answer (score 2):

Okay it turns out that you can do this via the `Tracing` tab in the `ODBC Data Source Administrator`. Just click on `Start Tracing Now`

Comment: guess you beat me to it :-)